# Displaying items from collection in a template

Tags: meteor

The below code is expected to insert a document of 3 pairs in the FooterButtons collection, then those values are shown as labels on 3 buttons in the footer template.

But when the "click .menuItem" is called, it only insert "YES" in the collection. Any idea why it is broker and best way to fix it? Thanks

Server and client code

```
FooterButtons = new Mongo.Collection('footerButtons');
```

Server code

```
Meteor.publish('footerButtons', function(){
    return FooterButtons.find();
});
```

Client code

```
Meteor.subscribe('footerButtons');

//---main_menu.js--------------------   
Template.mainMenu.events({  
  'click .menuItem': function (event) {  
   FooterButtons.insert({button:"NO", button:"EXTRA", button:"YES"});  
  }
});

//---footer.html---------------
<template name="footer">
{{#each footerButtons}}
<h1>
  <button class="col-xs-4" type="button">{{button}}</button>
</h1>
{{/each}}
</template>

//---footer.js---------------
Template.footer.helpers({
 footerButtons: function(){
  return FooterButtons.find();
 }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This command is totally wrong for the mongo insertion

```
   FooterButtons.insert({button:"NO", button:"EXTRA", button:"YES"});
```

If you create a javascript object,

```
var obj = {button:"NO", button:"EXTRA", button:"YES"};
```

since all the keys is duplicated, your object will only has one key which has the value of the last one: Yes

You need to insert one by one

```
   FooterButtons.insert({button:"NO"});  
   FooterButtons.insert({button:"EXTRA"});  
   FooterButtons.insert({button:"YES"});
```